# Sort two columns of datagrid with checkbox flex

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, apache-flex, datagrid, actionscript

I have 5-6 columns in DataGrid in flex application.

```
<s:DataGrid id="recordGrid" dataProvider="{dxList}">
```

**Grid:**

```
Selected  Name   field2   field2   field3
```

In first column has CheckBox.

Second column contains Name. and So on...

Currently No checkbox is selected.   Now, user select multiple checkbox randomly and Click on header(selected). then it will sort checkbox first.(I Done it).

But, My problem is Second field is also sort **alphabetically**.

All selected records come top with their Name alphabetically. Then after unchecked Record will be display in alphabetically sorted.

I Do following to sort record by checkbox selected:

```
<s:GridColumn dataField="selected" sortDescending="true">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're using the sort api of the dataProvider.

Example taken from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flex/Grid/SortingaDataGridonmultiplecolumns.htm

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    initialize="initDP();" width="550" height="400">
    <mx:Script>

        import mx.events.DataGridEvent;
        import mx.collections.*;
        private var myDPColl:ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        private var sortA:Sort;
        private var sortByColumn1:SortField;
        private var sortByColumn2:SortField;
        private var sortByColumn3:SortField;
        private var myDP:Array = [{Column1:'A', Column2:'AA',Column3:11.99, Column4: true},
                                  {Column1:'B', Column2:'BB',Column3:10.99, Column4: false},
                                  {Column1:'C', Column2:'CC',Column3:12.99, Column4: true},
                                  {Column1:'D', Column2:'VV',Column3:11.99, Column4: false},
                                  {Column1:'E', Column2:'EE',Column3:11.99, Column4: true},
                                  {Column1:'F', Column2:'FF',Column3:14.99, Column4: true},
                                  {Column1:'G', Column2:'GG',Column3:5.99,  Column4: true}
        ];
        private function initDP():void {
            myDPColl = new ArrayCollection(myDP);
            sortA = new Sort();
            sortByColumn1 = new SortField("Column1", true, true);
            sortByColumn2 = new SortField("Column2", true);
            sortByColumn3 = new SortField("Column3", true);
            sortA.fields=[sortByColumn1, sortByColumn2];
            myDPColl.sort=sortA;
            myDPColl.refresh();
            myGrid.dataProvider = myDPColl;
            myGrid.rowCount = myDPColl.length +1;
        }
        private function headRelEvt(event:DataGridEvent):void {
            sortA.fields[2] = sortA.fields[1];
            sortA.fields[1] = sortA.fields[0];
            if (event.columnIndex==0) {
                sortA.fields[0] = sortByColumn1;
            } else if (event.columnIndex==1) {
                sortA.fields[0] = sortByColumn2;
            } else {
                sortA.fields[0] = sortByColumn3;}
                myDPColl.sort = sortA;
                myDPColl.refresh();
                event.preventDefault();
        }

    </mx:Script>
    <mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="100%" headerRelease="headRelEvt(event);">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn minWidth="120" dataField="Column1"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn minWidth="200" dataField="Column2"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="75" dataField="Column3"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>

</mx:Application>
```